# What's special about the `+string` idiom in Angular/TS?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the Angular 2 official tutorial they instruct you to type this method for the `HeroService` class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => 
this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']));
}
```

They explain the + sign is a way of converting the param, which is a string, to a number.

1) Why is that needed? As long as `getHero()` takes a number as a parameter, isn't TypeScript expected to perform type conversion, or not doing that is precisely its point?

2) Why `<number>params['id']` or `params['id'] as number` doesn't work there? At least, that's been my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that needed? As long as getHero() takes a number as a parameter, isn't TypeScript expected to perform type conversion, or not doing that is precisely its point?

No. TypeScript doesn't automatically convert *string*s to *number*s.

> Why params['id'] or params['id'] as number doesn't work there

It doesn't work because a Type *assertion* is not a *type cast*. More on assertions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html